# DialogFragment Position Listener

Tags: dialogfragment

Is there any way to determine when the x position of a dialog fragment changes?

I have an animation on my dialog fragment. The animation increases the height of a textview when the edittext (that's within the textview) gets focus and decreases the height when the edittext loses focus. When I press back I want the edit text to lose focus, but it still has it. So now I am trying to figure out how to determine when the x position of the dialog fragment changes when the keyboard disappears, so that I can clear the focus when I press back.